How to choose a BMS for a 280 Ah LiFePO4 Battery?
I’m using a 12 V 280 Ah LiFePO4 battery pack https://www.eco-worthy.com/products/lifepo4-12v-280ah-lithium-iron-phosphate-battery and I need to select a suitable Battery Management System (BMS).
The BMS should:
Handle high current (around 200 A).
Interface with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi, preferably via serial (UART, CAN, or Bluetooth).
Monitor and report voltages, current draw, and battery levels.
What factors should I think about when considering a BMS for this setup?

prestonferry - (a) Our systems (and some users) detected that the latest version was partly or completely copied from a genAI tool like ChatGPT. This site's current genAI policy allows genAI content, within limits, but the genAI tool used must be disclosed & the content referenced, as explained in that linked rule. Currently this question is missing those required details & has been "closed" until you edit the question to add them. (b) The question is unclear e.g. it asks what interfaces & features are important, but it already states the requirements. Please clarify

prestonferry - I see that instead of disclosing the genAI tool used and referencing the generated content by following the genAI policy, the question has just been slightly rewritten. That's a shame as it seems to be trying to hide the previous use of genAI. However, for the moment, I'll reopen the question to the community.

@SamGibson I thought the rule for AI generation was because it’s normally used to create things that others could think are accomplishments made by humans, which does not apply here… I also thought you were an AI which is why I thought it was no harm done, I apologize but if this doesn’t work I don’t really know what else to do… I’m not really sure how to rewrite any other way… I was also not privy on how to announce that the question itself was AI generated…

prestonferry - (a) You're right that the main concern about genAI is around answers. But in the SE rule I linked, it specifically refers to genAI content, not just answers. This was done deliberately, so that it applies to questions, answers & comments i.e. any content. (b) I'm not AI :) but even if I was, that doesn't change the fact that there's a site rule involved, which shouldn't be ignored. Q/A/C with unreferenced genAI content are eligible for potential deletion, as explained in that policy.

(continued) (c) The method of disclosing & referencing genAI content is explained in the genAI policy I linked, with an example, under the heading "How do I reference content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?". I would always advise people not to hide the use of genAI, as it looks worse for the author when it gets discovered later. || Just to note that the genAI policy is subject to possible future change, as we plan to consult about genAI content on this site, hopefully soon. Which reminds me, I've got some unreferenced genAI content to go & delete :)

@SamGibson I understand that, however when I reworded it, it seemed that you weren’t pleased… Not that it matters, but I’d think that would at least be enough for it to not violate that rule… Also wanted to say, I had only mentioned AI because I thought that the flag was probably going off and an AI detector was wrongly removing my post, not a real person… Wasn’t trying to get around a rule but rather trying to get around what I thought was some faulty system…

The factors should be:

BMS for LFP Li-ion cells (aka LiFePO4)
Protector BMS with a 200 A protector switch
Single port (just the P terminals, no C terminals)
Include a wired digital communication link (not wireless, therefore, not Bluetooth)

There are only a few BMSs that meet these specs, and I am afraid that a few of them cannot be trusted at 200 A (they blow up).
I would recommend one, but then your question would run afoul of the "Product recommendations" rule.

Is there any particular website I can look, or anything specific I could lookup on Google?

Davide Andrea - Hi, In an answer you can choose whether or not to make recommendations, as long as any affiliation is disclosed & there has been a non-product answer given too (as you've kindly done here). The rule is that questions asking for recommendations aren't allowed. || It's not uncommon for people to mention specific MCUs, logic ICs, MOSFETs etc. as examples in an answer. But there's no obligation on you to do so - it's totally your choice, as long as there's a long-lived "non recommendation" answer too (in case the recommendation becomes obsolete etc.) Does that help?

@SamGibson It does, thank you.

The specified Eco-Worthy LiFePO4 battery pack already contains a BMS inside the pack.  You don't need anything external to protect this battery pack.
If you want to interface with a computer for battery monitoring, best bet is buy a different battery that Provides digital access to the internal BMS.
If that is not possible, then you really are wanting a "battery monitor" for voltage and current (using measurement shunt rated for max application current compatible with external wiring and fusing), not a Battery Management System.
